# How to declare variable in sql update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to update with a new variable

let's say I wanted to do the following

```
update T
set T.property1 = (declare @temp varch(20)
                           @temp = 'testing')
from #temp_table_name T
```

is this possible.  I need to update a table but the new element is the end result of a series of complicated statements and it would be a lot easier to define some variables along the way to handle intermediate outputs.  What is the correct syntax for what I'm trying to do above because it's not working

Answer (score 5):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
DECLARE @temp varchar(20)
SET @temp = 'testing, or the result of a query maybe?'

UPDATE T SET T.property1 = @temp 
FROM #temp_table_name T
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Move all of those statements into a [scalar valued user-defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386973.aspx) and then in your update statement do this:

```
update T
set T.property1 = dbo.myUdf(...)
from #temp_table_name T
```

where `...` are any parameters it may need from the row to do its job.